# ASP string format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, string-formatting

i was used with php to use printf to build my strings, but i cannot find anything similar with asp and i end up writing crap like:

```
WrapTag="<"&Tag&">"&Text&"&nbsp;</"&Tag&">"
```

instead i would liek to write something more readable, like:

```
WrapTag=String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{2}>",Tag,Text,Tag)
```

as it was shown with this url:
http://idunno.org/archive/2004/07/14/122.aspx but it is not working.
Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: _What_ is not working? `String.Format` should work just as you have posted without an issue.

Comment: Your code should work, please provide the error message. Note that you would only have to provide `Tag` once; `String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", Tag, Text);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you show is correct.

You don't have to send in the tag name twice, you can use the same value twice in the format:

```
WrapTag = String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>",Tag,Text)
```